# How to fix broken packages in Kali Linux?

Tags: package-management, kali-linux, upgrade, dependencies

I was trying to update and upgrade my packages but when i executed the following command :

```
sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt update
```

The following message appeared :

```
Hit:1 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                            
Hit:2 http://kali.cs.nctu.edu.tw/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
767 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnustep-base-runtime : Depends: gnustep-base-common (= 1.27.0-3) but 1.26.0-7 is to be installed
 libgnustep-base1.27 : Depends: gnustep-base-common (= 1.27.0-3) but 1.26.0-7 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

I have tried to execute commands below :

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt install -f
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

But it still error.

What should i do now ?...
Thank you in advance....

Answer (score 5):

1st:    try the apt-get command (if you didn't) so

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

then these command will help clean your dependencies

```
sudo apt-get autoclean &&  sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

those helped in a similar problem. I hope they also helped you ;)

Answer (score 3):

So this worked for me

I reinstall libwacom-common and libwacom-bin with:

```
sudo apt reinstall libwacom-common && sudo apt reinstall libwacom-bin
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing

sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-missing
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest running

```
    sudo apt-get autoclean &&  sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get update --fix-missing && sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-missing
```